# XCode OAuth request access_token call "401 3-> HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, magento, oauth

I've managed to get to the third part of the OAuth protocol implemented by Magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

First the request token call returns a token, i present the user the authorization dialog in a UIWebView and extract the token/verifier after the user has pressed "Authorize".

I call the access_token url with these parameters

```
OAuth realm="", 
oauth_timestamp="1339756083",
oauth_nonce="d1dc184d236756c42210b746a887edb5bd69cf44", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_consumer_key="{censored}", 
oauth_version="1.0", 
oauth_token="912i72lcu6vzlwk6a3vdj4a3sstbdzqp",
oauth_token_secret="t5cg9qlykkk9411iv0rbul0gnw9fsa0m", 
oauth_verifier="9vu02kbymodo63pve091otffvy53rhlf",
oauth_signature="fDwWGeJhatIX6kK4nb%2Bagp4C%2FxU%3D"
```

This is part of my Obj-C code

```
NSMutableArray* values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.requestToken,self.requestSecret,verifier, nil];
NSMutableArray* keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"oauth_token", @"oauth_token_secret", @"oauth_verifier", nil];
NSDictionary* extraParams = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

OAuth* oauth = [[OAuth alloc] initWithConsumerKey:OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY andConsumerSecret:OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET];

NSString* authHeader = [oauth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST" andUrl:ACCESS_TOKEN_URL andParams:extraParams];
NSLog(@"%@", authHeader);
ASIHTTPRequest* request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ACCESS_TOKEN_URL]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:authHeader];
```

This is what magenta tells me in return

```
2012-06-15 12:28:06.052 Versmissen[2175:707] 401 3-> HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required  -> (null) -> http://{censored}/oauth/token
```

However, 401 3 is NOT in the list of OAuth errors explained in the API. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

fixed. Need to sign the authentication header with the request_secret

NSString* authHeader = [self.oauth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST" andUrl:ACCESS_TOKEN_URL andParams:extraParams andTokenSecret:self.requestSecret];

:)